# firebase rule to make sure a owner of comment has access to read, write and any other user to only like it. number_check is the user table

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The following is the database structure and i want to make sure the owner of the comment whose user_id is part of the comment object to have read and write access to the comment and all other users have read access to comment and the ability to like it to increase like_count:

[image]

The following is the security rule I came up with:

```
   {
  "rules": {
    "comments": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
      ".write": "(newData.parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).val() != null && newData.parent().child('comments').hasChildren().hasChildren().child('user_id').val() == auth.uid)",
      "$commentId": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).val() != null",
        ".write": "(newData.parent().parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).val() != null && !newData.parent().parent().child('comments').hasChildren().hasChildren().child('like_count'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the code for the operation you are having problems with? 2) What is the problem with these rules and that operation?

Comment: I want to make sure that only owner of a comment can do CRUD operations on it, however other users should be allowed to increase like_count, and set is_reply and has_replies fields only. The above rules does not work as expected

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own. They only do something when code accesses the database. Edit your question to include the minimum code with whcih you can reproduce the problem, in a way that we can all run it with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

So, for read better will be:

```
".read": "root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
```

".write" is more complicated:

- You need to only allow edit in like_count, and you need to allow for only one like per user
- Proper way to do this will be expand structure of your "post", something like like_list, here or in other place to protect data transfer from growing when post will be download by client

So in "comment" node you want to allow every auth user to .write and .read, they will be able to add new comment  then (upper rules will be fine for this).
For $commentId node rules will look like:

```
".write":".data.child('user_id').val() == auth.uid"
```

You can link like_list to a clinet by adding user_id to the "like / $ commentId" node and setting listener in firebase funtions for this node. adding new user_id will fire "write" event and then call function to secure increase the value of like_count.

You can archive it with a firebase-function and transaction.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/firebase/firebase_write_transactional_data.htm

If you really don`t want to change schema then you need to secure every single child of comment, like:

```
"$commentID":{
       "comment":{ ".write":"".data.parent().child('user_id').val() == auth.uid" ),
       ...//things allowed to edit by owner
       "like_count":{
            ".write":"root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            ".validate":"newData.val() == data.val() + 1"
       }
 }
```

But this will not secure post from giving more than one like per user.